# things that look like long vowels but aren't

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, long-vowels

Are there words written with "ei" or "ou" that are pronounced with both vowels instead of as a long vowel? I think this is true in cases like 拾う and している, but are there cases of it happening where you'd expect to find a long vowel?

I ask because I thought I heard 姪 pronounced this way.

Comment: スペイン is pronounced with both vowels.

Comment: Related:  [Questions about 背負う](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12697/78).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

For 拾う and している, I think everybody pronounces them with *ou* and *ei*.

For 姪, I would pronounce it *mei*, but I'm not convinced that some people wouldn't pronounce it *mee*. In the case of 姪御{めいご}, which is sonkeigo for 姪, I think even I would pronounce it *meego*.

I don't know if there are strict rules about when to pronounce it either way, but here are some guidelines that I think might help:

**Hiragana and kanji**

1. Pronounce them as written if part of different words/morphemes/kanji, i.e. している, 乗っていく, 子牛{こうし}. I put 拾う under this rule as well, considering ～う a present-tense ending.
2. Pronounce kun-yomi as written, but on-yomi (when it doesn't go across 2 kanji) as long vowels, i.e. 名 *mee*, but 姪 *mei*. 塔 *too*, but 問う *tou*. In the middle of morphemes, though, like in 儲{もう}かる *mookaru*, pronounce as long vowel, even for kun-yomi. Not sure if 姪御 as *meego* would fall under this exception as well, though.
3. Certain common words, like もう, こう, そう, どう are pronounced with long vowels.

**Katakana**

Simple, pronounce as long vowel when using ー, otherwise separately, i.e. スペイン *supein*, but ページ *peeji*

Sorry for being wishy-washy, but I think with these guidelines, you should be OK in 99% of the cases. I'm curious too if there are any standard rules for this.

Comment: I don't understand your point (2). Most long vowels in kun-yomi _do_ occur morpheme-internally, and most morpheme-internal orthographic diphthongs are actually long vowels. For example, 今日【きょう】, which comes from けふ, or 鱏【えい】, which comes from えひ. In rare cases they span two morphemes, e.g. 日向【ひゅうが】 (← ひむか) and 狩人【かりゅうど】 (← かりびと). (These are both exceptional instances of ウ音便.)

Comment: @ZhenLin You are right, my answer isn't well thought through. I'll edit it when I have a bit more time