# Does おお sound different from おう?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

I know おう sounds like a long o, but does おお sound the same, or should it be pronounced differently?

Comment: お sounds kind of like "oh." I think you are thinking of "oo" like "boo". that "oo" sound is closer to う. おお is like ohoh (you can blend them together or not) and おう sounds like oh-oo. my 2 cents.

Comment: I think that with a few exceptions, おう is /o:/ within a single morpheme, and /ou/ when it crosses morpheme boundaries.  おお is always /o:/.

Comment: We have a question with some discussion of おう: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4718/1478

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that with a few exceptions, `おう` is /oː/ within a single morpheme, and /ou/ when it crosses morpheme boundaries.  `おお` is always /oː/.  The same thing is true of other kana pairs like `こう・こお`, `そう・そお`, and so on.

For example, look at the following pair of words:

```
  追う　　おう　　/ou/
  王　　　おう　　/oː/
```

`追う` can be divided into the root `ow` and the verb ending morpheme `u`.  The /w/ disappears before /u/, so we're left with /o/ and /u/ in separate morphemes, pronounced together as /ou/.  The same thing happens with other verbs that end this way, so `思う` is pronounced /omou/, not /omo:/.  In contrast, `王` contains `おう` within a single morpheme, so it's pronounced as a long vowel /oː/.  You can make any number of similar comparisons:

```
  沿う　　そう　　/sou/
  そう　　そう　　/soː/
```

One tricky case is forms like `行こう`.  If you follow the traditional analysis and call this the 未然形＋助動詞「う」, it *looks like* `行こ` and `う` are separate morphemes, but that doesn't fit with our rule so far--this form is always pronounced /oː/, not /ou/.  In fact, separating between `行こ` and `う` is an artifact of analyzing Japanese in kana; romanizing makes things a bit clearer.  Instead of `iko.u`, we can divide it into `ik.ou`, giving us the root `ik` plus the hortative suffix `ou`.  Once we do so, we can see that `ou` doesn't 
cross morpheme boundaries, so it makes sense that it's pronounced /oː/.

---

The above rule mostly works, but we can come up with some exceptions like `今日` /kjoː/ or `おはよう` /ohajoː/.  What do they have in common?  They were historically subject to a class of sound changes called [ウ音便](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A6%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF#.E3.82.A6.E9.9F.B3.E4.BE.BF).  Let's look at these one at a time:

- `今日` was originally `今` /ke/ + `日` /pu/.  The consonant /p/ turned into /Φ/ and then was lost, leaving /keu/.  This was subject to the sound change /eu/ to /joː/, giving /kjoː/.  Modern kana usage respelled `けふ` as `きょう` to reflect this pronunciation, obscuring the fact that it began its life as two separate morphemes.
- `おはよう` was originally the honorific prefix `御` /o/ + the root `早` /haja/ + the adjective ending `く` /ku/.  Again the consonant before the /u/ dropped out, giving /ohajau/, which was subject to the sound change /au/ to /oː/, giving /ohajoː/.

In both cases, the sound changes created long vowels that cross morpheme boundaries, and modern kana usage respelled them with an お段 kana plus `う`.  In cases like these, the pronunciation is /oː/ rather than /ou/.

Comment: Necropost, but 行こう comes from ウ音便 too. The correct analysis should be 未然形 /~a/ + う + ウ音便; `ikau -> ikoo`. For some reason traditional grammar uses the unworkable kludge of proposing a 未然形 ending in /o/ though...

Comment: @user54609 Well, that's not a synchronic process, it's history.  It begins and ends life as /oː/ in modern Japanese.  Shibatani addresses this problem by proposing a seventh 活用形 with `/-o/` that う can attach to.  I think the ending is a single morpheme, personally...

Comment: Well, Japanese grammarians are still content to call あって 連用形＋て...

Comment: @user54609 True, **some** Japanese grammarians are.  And if you're content with that, then I see no reason not to describe `ikou` as underlyingly `ikau`, as you suggest!

Comment: Well, personally I would prefer to add two 活用形s, a "音便連用形" and "音便未然形". The former would in particular be really useful without constantly invoking  diachronic sound changes to explain て, たり, た, たら, etc.

Comment: Also, I never argued that おう is not a single morpheme. A 未然形 doesn't really add a morpheme; I agree that such an analysis is too bound to kana. It is simply an irregular way of binding morphemes to the root, namely by adding in vowels. Historically endings with the same stem vowels had related meanings, so it makes sense to group them into things like 未然形 (talking about unfulfilled things), 已然形 (talking about fulfilled things), 連用形 (random other stuff), etc.