# Questions about 背負う

Tags: words, usage, conjugations, dialects, homophonic-kanji

`背負う` is pronounced `せおう`, but many dictionaries also list a second pronunciation as `しょう`.

1. I've never heard it pronounced as `しょう` in practice.  In what situations does it have this pronunciation?   Is that only an archaic pronunciation, or is it still in use?  Is it a regional/dialectical thing?  Is one free to pronounce it with either way, unrestricted?
2. `せおう` (or `おう`, rather) conjugates as a `五段`.  Does `しょう` also conjugate as a `五段`?

> - ます形　→　しょいます
> - ない形　→　しょわない
> - ～て･た形　→　しょって・た
> - 命令形　→　しょえ
> - 仮定形　→　しょえば
> - 可能形　→　しょえる
> - 意志形　→　しょおう

Comment: There are separate dictionary entries for both words in [大辞林 and 大辞泉](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%83%8C%E8%B2%A0%E3%81%86).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference I perceive is that しょう sounds slightly more "intimate" as if it's a regional dialect. But this doesn't mean せおう is less of everyday language. Probably I feel this way because the pronunciation is a naturally slurred version of せおう (i.e., /seo/ -> /syo/), which is most likely the result of a natural sound shift like [音便](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF).

The tricky thing is that しょう here is not a homonym of しょう as in 賞, 章, and 小. While they look exactly the same in kana, しょう as 背負う does not have the double mora お. It's しょ as one mora plus う as another mora, i.e., it's not the same pronunciation as しょー.

As for its conjugation, it's 五段 as you guessed.

Comment: `The tricky thing is that しょう here is not a homonym of しょう as in 賞, 章, and 小`.  That's a bold claim and I'm not quite sure I understand how they *could* be pronounced differently.  Do you have a source that can verify this?

Comment: Haha!  I guess you can add him if you want.  Do you know of somewhere online that has audio pronunciations of these so I can hear how they're different?

Comment: @istrasci I think it's like how 思う isn't pronounced オモー.  The う is a different morpheme so it can't represent the second mora of a long vowel.

Comment: Oh, like "show" vs. "shoh"/"shō"?

Answer (score 4):

One can hear しょって used often when talking about rucksacks or backpacks.

> リュックサックを[背負]{しょ}って[歩]{ある}く

There isn't really much difference (しょう pronunciation is from せおう anyway), though, and people use them quite interchangeably.  Though, sometimes the nuance of しょう can be such that it is [迷惑]{めいわく}...

However, there is one situation, when one's talking about someone being vain or full of themselves, where one can use しょってる and not せおってる.  One hears this usage often in [落語]{らくご}...

Answer (score 2):

### Addendum: Pronunciation

The verb 背負う has two modern pronunciations: せおう, and しょう.  From a modern perspective, it's a little befuddling how these two interrelate.  If we look at the past, however, the story comes clear.

The version starting with し is sometimes analyzed by modern speakers as the し being a slurred or otherwise shifted pronunciation of せ.  However, historically, it is worth noting that せ was itself formerly pronounced more like //ʃe// (as in English *shed*).  The non-fricative sibilant //se// version appears some time after the 1603 日葡辞書 (*Nippo Jisho*, "Japanese-Portuguese Dictionary"), where all of the せ sounds are spelled ⟨xe⟩ instead -- and where that ⟨x⟩ was the Portuguese spelling at the time of the "sh" sound in modern English (more or less -- for strict phonologists, I'm uncertain if that was the [voiceless postalveolar fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_postalveolar_fricative) [[ʃ]], the [voiceless alveolo-palatal fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_fricative) [[ɕ]] as in modern Tokyo Japanese, the [voiceless retroflex fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_retroflex_fricative) [[ʂ]] (unlikely, I think), or some other specific phone).  Note all of the entries in the *X antes do E* section ("X before E") [starting from the bottom right of this page](https://books.google.com/books?id=TFJAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA292-IA1#v=onepage&q&f=false), including such otherwise-familiar terms as "Xecai. *Mundo.*" (Sekai. *World.*)

So the difference in reading between せおう and しょう is not a seemingly arbitrary rearrangement of consonant and vowel values, but instead the unsurprising result of a contraction, as //ʃeou// shifted to just //ʃou//.

According to the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 entry [here at Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%83%8C%E8%B2%A0-2049668), the shorter しょう reading appears first in 1278, well within the time period when せ was still pronounced as a fricative //ʃe//, and thus a contraction from //ʃeou// to //ʃou// would not have been all that exceptional.

Comment: One more followup, since this question has become active — I have it listed here in my (web) dictionary resource that the pitch accent of the reading せおう (中高 1) is different to しょう (平板). Is there any way this can be possible, or is it a mistake in the data source?

Comment: There appears to be a not-uncommon trend towards "flattening", whereby words lose their downstep.  I think I recall seeing recent threads where [Darius Jahandarie](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/3097/darius-jahandarie) has had some rather detailed things to say about Japanese phonology, going well beyond my current expertise.  Just for this word, it doesn't strike me as unusual - the contraction also obscures the distinction between the two parts, the 背【せ】 upon which one 負【お】う-s a burden, so the change in pitch seems reasonable enough to me - subjectively speaking, anyway. :)

Comment: しょう is indeed heiban. It’s actually not 平板化, as しょう is a very old word and has always had that accent. It’s actually that せおう used to be heiban (like most compound wago verbs) and then shifted to being accented (again like most compound wago verbs), but since しょう no longer seemed like a compound to people it just stayed flat.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, thank you, very interesting! Where have you learned so much about pitch patterns and their history?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I've just spent a lot of time (probably ~1k hrs) working on getting native-level accent over the few years, and while a huge amount of it was done by-ear, in the process I've probably read near a hundred academic/survey papers on pitch accent, as well as looked up probably 20,000+ pitch entries in dictionaries, so I have a lot of surrounding technical/linguistic/historical knowledge about it too. The full 日本国語大辞典 instance (only digitally available on JapanKnowledge, not monokakido) lists historical pitch accents, which is what I used to confirm this one.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, thank you very much for the JapanKnowledge pointer, hadn't heard of that site before, and didn't know that the fuller 日本国語大辞典 includes _historical_ pitch patterns as well, that is super useful (for my own word-nerd inclinations, anyway )!