# 思う pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I checked in google translate but I wanted to be sure. Is 思う pronounced as "omou" or "omoo"? Usually when there is a お (or こ、ど etc), followed by a う, the う is pronounced as お, but I was not sure if that was the case with verbs as well.

Comment: Related: [Questions about 背負う](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12697/78).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is "omou" not "omoo" at least I've actually heard it pronounced this way.

- In 1 word "oo" or "ou" both are long "o".
- In two words put together, you have to know how they are pronounced
  seperatly and it doesn't really change. If you have a verb ending in
  ou then the final u will be "u" not "o".

When I have doubts about the pronunciation of a word I rather use this [site](http://forvo.com/word/%E5%BF%83%E3%81%AB%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86/) because Google is not too reliable ...

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought. Thanks for the useful site too!

Answer (score 5):

思う is pronounced "omou" with a distinct "u" sound rather than a long "o" because there is a morpheme barrier between the "o" and the "u."

Comment: thanks! I don't know what is a morpheme barrier though

Comment: @FelipeMüller Syllable boundary.

Comment: @oals That's not what it is. If you don't know what a morpheme is, you can always look it up on Wikipedia, but it would be easier to put into context with some experience in linguistics.

Comment: isn't there always a syllable boundary between う and anything else, since う is a syllable? (or is it?)

Comment: "Morpheme boundary" here refers to the way that the う on the end belongs to a different grammatical portion of the word -- this う is the verb ending, and it changes when the verb conjugates.  The う in そう (as in そうです) or in ふつう (as in 普通) does _not_ change at all, and _is_ part of the same grammatical functional unit as the preceding mora -- so the う takes on the phonetic value of the preceding mora: becoming `/o/` in そう, and staying as `/u/` in 普{ふ}通{つう}.  Similarly, the final い in -しい adjectives (like うつくしい or ほしい or まぶしい) is morphemically separate, and is thus spelled separate in romaji.